# Is there a way to change which duplicate answer is deleted?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers, duplicate-answers

I posted a duplicate answer to two separate threads, one about calling JS from C++ and one about calling JS from C. I think they're fundamentally different domains, but my solution was mainly aimed at C. The post about C++ has more votes, so it was arbitrarily decided to delete the C one. In retrospect, if I had to choose, I would leave the C answer up, as it feels like the answer would be better received by that community.

Is there a way to undelete one, and delete the other one?

C answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74620489/2289030

C++ answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74620424/2289030

Relevant meta discussion: [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions)

Comment: It's not arbitrary, a mod chose to do it

Comment: It's arbitrary in which one the mod chose, not that they chose (the reasons for which they helpfully linked in the meta discussion)

Comment: It's also generally not arbitrary which one the mod choses, they keep the oldest one. In this case [the one posted at 21:27](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74620424) was kept and the [one posted 7 minutes later at 21:35](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74620489) was removed.

Comment: You can flag your post as "in need of moderator intervention" and explain what you'd like to happen and why. Mod deletion can only be reversed by another moderator so you'll need their assistance to make the change.

Comment: What Henry said is correct.  I went ahead and swapped them for you, though.

Comment: The flag for review is helpful to know, thanks!